# Can the url-pattern in a servlet filter-mapping point to a servlet in another domain?

Tags: servlets, cors, servlet-filters

Can the url-pattern in a servlet filter-mapping point to a servlet in another domain?

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In the url-pattern putting /* would make this filter apply to all servlets in the application. 
Is there a way to apply filter for servlets in another domain/application?
If so, what is the url pattern I should use.

I tried putting the full path to the domain name and servlet, but an error was thrown and my application didn't start up.

Comment: No, this is not possible. It is expected only local URL mapping there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The filter mapping only specifies a URL pattern for URLs that hit your application.

If you mean you have your application running on multiple domains and you want the filter to only be mapped for a specific domain, there is not a way to do this with the filter mapping. If you mean you want to have the filter *inside* your application affect a servlet *outside* of your web application, this is not possible.